# How can I set the 'password last set' date of an AD account?

Tags: active-directory, password, password-management, window-server-2019

In a development environment I want to modify the 'password last set' date of my AD accounts so they won't begin to expire during development phase, but as soon as the environment becomes a production environment.

How can I change that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set it to an arbitrary value, but you can set it to the current date via the following steps:

1. Get the account:

   ```
   $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $UserName -Properties pwdLastSet
   ```
2. Set the value to 0:

   ```
   $user.pwdLastSet = 0
   Set-ADUser -Instance $user
   ```
3. Set the value to -1:

   ```
   $user.pwdLastSet = -1
   Set-ADUser -Instance $user
   ```

After that, the account behaves as if the password has just been changed.

---

[Semicolon](https://serverfault.com/users/340559/semicolon) contributed through the comments, that you can also achieve the above through:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $UserName -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true | Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false
```

---

FYI, you can apply the same logic to local accounts:

```
net user $UserName /LOGONPASSWORDCHG:YES
net user $UserName /LOGONPASSWORDCHG:NO
```

Comment: ChangePasswordAtLogon variant not working. After that account password became expired.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to reset the pasword clock is open ADusers and computers
find the user/users in question (you can do a bulk change by highlighting several users)
On the account tab - tick the change at next login and click apply and then untick the same box and apply again

that will reset the password last set to the time and date you applied it

hope that helps